# Change non refundable ticket into a different ticket

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines

I had a non refundable Paris to Lima round trip ticket which I won't use. Instead, my wife will fly from Lima to Paris. Question: is there any way for her to use my ticket so she can pay less, that is, some sort of ticket "transfer" from a person to a different person?

Note: she'll travel with our child.

Comment: And what did the fare details have to say about refunds and changes when you booked the ticket?

Comment: pnuts: Iberia / Gagravarr: it says "Changes permitted before departure with a €120 penalty | No refunds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll have much luck:

1. The ticket is not refundable.
2. Passengers are different.
3. The number of passengers are different.
4. You are changing the flight (yes, even though you are flying the reverse leg, to an airline this is a separate flight).

The only thing I can think of in this situation is to change the name on the ticket to your wife (there will be a charge for this) and then pay to add your child to ticket (even if she/he is an infant and doesn't require a seat).

Then, simply don't fly the outbound leg - and fly the inbound leg (the return leg - Lima - Paris).

Comment: @pnuts good point.

Comment: "Via an MCO" : what does that mean?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid "don't fly the outbound leg - and fly the inbound leg" this is very bad advice, and usually not possible - the airline will cancel all remaining tickets once one segment (here the outbound leg) is not flown, so he'd lose that anyway, and waste more money for useless change of names!